# выбор строки из таблицы и перевод в число. javascript

Tags: javascript

нужно выбрать в переменную строку из ячейки взноса: 150 руб и перевести ее в число без "руб", как такое реализовать не пойму, подскажите

```
<form id="t">
    <div class="c">
        <div class="h">
            <dl class="e">
                <dt></dt>
                <dd class="23"></dd>
                <dt></dt>
                <dd class="23"></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl class="info">
                <dt>Цена:</dt>
                <dd>2000 руб</dd>
                <dt>Взнос:</dt>
                <dd>150 руб</dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: а вы как то пытались проблему решить самостоятельно?)

Comment: пытаюсь, JS только обучаюсь(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так

```
var q = document.querySelectorAll('dd');
for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
    console.log(parseInt(q[i].innerText))
}
```

Comment: если я правильно понял то "querySelectorAll" выберет же все элементы "dd", а нужен именно второй "dd" в котором сумма 150

Comment: Совершенно верно, тогда используйте `var q = document.querySelectorAll('.info>dd:last-child'); console.log(parseInt(q[0].innerText));`

Comment: Вместо `innerText` производительней использовать `textContent`

Comment: Можно и так сделать =)

Comment: а лучше добавить `id` элементу, и обращаться по мнему

Comment: @teran, зачем? изначально было неизвестно что нужен только один элемент. Никто не спорит, что этот кусок кода можно шлифовать и шлифовать.

Comment: @rafnsvartr затем, что автор написал, что только изучает JS и т.п. Скорее всего, он даже не знает, о такой возможности. Более того, указано, что нужен именно второй элемент.